# How to understand the $o(1)$ notation in the note by Zhao for the Probabilistic Method book?

Tags: asymptotics, probabilistic-method

In Zhao's [note](https://yufeizhao.com/pm/probmethod_notes.pdf)(page 86) for Noga Alon's *Probabilistic Methods*:

> Remark 8.1.4. When $\mathbb{P}(A_i)=o(1)$, Harris inequality gives us
> $$
> \mathbb{P}(X=0)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bar{A}_{1} \cdots \bar{A}_{k}\right) \geq \mathbb{P}\left(\bar{A}_{1}\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(\bar{A}_{k}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right)\right)=e^{-(1+o(1)) \sum_{i-1}^{k} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{i}\right)}=e^{-(1+o(1)) \mu}
> $$

I was confused by the $o(1)$ notations here:

1. What does it mean by $\mathbb{P}(A_i)=o(1)$?   I understand it when we say $f(n)=o(1)$ it means that $f(n)\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$. But by $\mathbb{P}(A_i)=o(1)$ I see no corresponding variable like $n$.
2. How does the second-to-last equation come from? Especially, how to understand the $o(1)$ in $e^{-(1+o(1)) \sum_{i-1}^{k} \mathbb{P}(A_{i})}$. What I know is that $1-x\le e^{-x}$ when $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to improve my question. I've been stucked on it for hours.

Comment: I’m not the downvoter, but I would advise you to “forget it”. Someone didn’t bother to make a precise statement (not explaining what variables are fixed and which ones aren’t) *and* it’s in a remark… if I were to hazard a guess, assume that $k$ is fixed while you have some sort of $A_i$-generating process depending on an exterior parameter $t$, and you know that, in some limit wrt $t$, the $P(A_i)$ are all very small, so you can write $1-P(A_i)=e^{-P(A_i)(1+o(1))}$…

Comment: @Mindlack Could you please specify how can I obtain $1-P\left(A_{i}\right)=e^{-P\left(A_{i}\right)(1+o(1))}$ when $P(A_i)$ is very small?  I'm really confused by this equation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you replace $P(A_i)$ with $x$, with $x$ small enough, you want to show that $1-x=e^{-x(1+o(1))}$. Then let $1-x=e^{-y}$: $y=-\ln(1-x)=x+o(x)=x(1+o(1))$.

Comment: I think $y=-\ln(1-x)=x+o(1)$, do you assume that $o(1)=o(x)$?

Comment: another question: why don't we just write $1-x=e^{-x}+o(1)$?

Comment: Because $x=o(1)$ as well so you would be “drowning” that information. And you want something that works well with the products.